# Add Bing Maps Reference to Windows Phone 8.1 project

Tags: c#, bing-maps, windows-phone-8.1

I want to add a reference to Bing Map in windows Phone 8.1 C# project. I have installed this package http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/224eb93a-ebc4-46ba-9be7-90ee777ad9e1/
But now I can't choose the dll under "Add Reference". If I try this for a Windows 8.1 project (Surface) I can choose the Bing Maps DLL and use the Map Element. How can I use the Bing Map under Windows Phone 8.1?
I tried this tutorial but it didn't work for me. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn456475.aspx

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Bing Maps SDK you are referring to is for Windows 8.1 apps, not Windows Phone 8.1. The maps for Windows Phone 8.1 are built into the WP8.1 SDK. You can find them under the Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Maps namespace. Here are some resources for developing with maps in WP8.1

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/dn615001.aspx

http://www.jayway.com/2014/04/18/windows-phone-8-1-for-developers-maps/

If you want to create maps in Windows 8.1 I recommend checking out my free ebook on the topic here: http://rbrundritt.wordpress.com/my-book/