# Add a Bing Map to Windows Phone 8.1 app (javascript)

Tags: javascript, windows-phone-8.1, bing-maps

I'm trying to build an app for WP8.1 in javasript. This app just has to show a map and some pins taken from a KML file. I've managed to do it for a windows store app (desktop/tablet) but can't find any documentation for mobile phone apps.

I've found this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/xaml/dn642089.aspx

But it uses XAML and VB/C#

and here some solutions: [Map APIs for windows PHONE 8.1 in HTML, CSS, JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24790300/map-apis-for-windows-phone-8-1-in-html-css-js)

but i tried them and don't succeed

is there an official guide to use Bing Maps in WP8.1 environment?

Thanks

Comment: You could try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24790300/map-apis-for-windows-phone-8-1-in-html-css-js and http://www.jayway.com/2014/04/18/windows-phone-8-1-for-developers-maps/

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I tried the solutions on first link but the first is a code hack (which is really unsafe, as it's not supported for future updates), the second link leads to a page which is not a howto.. but an explanation of API changes in specific cases... i need something much more basic.. like create a map and add a simple pin :)
Thank anyway!!

Comment: You have already done that for windows store app, so doesn't the same code work here?Its a winRT app right?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't.. as for windows store APP i have to add a reference to the SDK in visual studio, thing that i'm not able to do it in WP environment, as explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23722058/add-bing-maps-reference-to-windows-phone-8-1-project

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this code sample: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Cross-Platform-Bing-Maps-e96600d5

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Unfortunately this example show how to implement the maps in Javascript for Windows 8.1 desktop and C# for Windows Phone 8.1

Comment: Take a closer look. The Windows Phone 8.1 is also using JavaScript. The JavaScript is being loaded through a browser control. This is how is was done in WP8. WP8.1 JavaScript apps do basically the same thing but just hide c# the browser code.

Comment: You're right :) I was frightened by the C# icon near the BingMaps_WP8_HTML5 Project... so (forgive me for my ignorance) the MainPage.xaml just calls the "index.html" page which in turn calls the "map.js" file and all the work is done in these 2 pages (index and map.js). Can I just use those 2 files? Or I need the XAML part too? Because all the project is already done in JS and i really don't know how to combine the new part with XAML and the old already written javascript code.
Thank you very much for your help!